# Unpermitted parameter error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When creating a record in Rails Controller, the following error occurs :

> Started POST "/spr_type_courses" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-27 08:11:01
>
> +0500 Processing by SprTypeCoursesController#create as HTML   Parameters: {"spr_type_course"=>{}} Unpermitted parameter:
>
> :spr_type_course   Sequence (3.0ms)  select us.sequence_name from
>
> all_sequences us where us.sequence_owner = 'PROJECT' and
>
> us.sequence_name = upper('SPR_TYPECOURSES_seq')   Primary Key (10.0ms)
>
> SELECT cc.column_name FROM all_constraints c, all_cons_columns cc
>
> WHERE c.owner = 'PROJECT' AND c.table_name = 'SPR_TYPECOURSES' AND
>
> c.constraint_type = 'P' AND cc.owner = c.owner AND cc.constraint_name
>
> = c.constraint_name   Primary Key Trigger (3.8ms)            SELECT trigger_name
>             FROM all_triggers
>             WHERE owner = 'PROJECT'
>               AND trigger_name = q'[PROJECT.SPR_TYPECOURSES_PKT]'
>               AND table_owner = 'PROJECT'
>               AND table_name = q'[SPR_TYPECOURSES]'
>               AND status = 'ENABLED'
>
> SQL (5.3ms)  INSERT INTO "PROJECT"."SPR_TYPECOURSES"
>
> ("TYPECOURSE_ID") VALUES (:a1)  [["typecourse_id", 3623]] Completed 500
>   Internal Server Error in 61ms
>
> ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (OCIError: ORA-01400: cannot insert
>
> NULL into ("PROJECT"."SPR_TYPECOURSES"."DATE_BEGIN"): INSERT INTO
>
> "PROJECT"."SPR_TYPECOURSES" ("TYPECOURSE_ID") VALUES (:a1)):
>
> app/controllers/spr_type_courses_controller.rb:17:in `create'

What can this mean and what needs to be done to correct it?

```
class SprTypeCoursesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_spr_type_course, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @spr_type_courses = SprTypeCourse.all

    render json: @spr_type_courses
  end

def show
  render json: @spr_type_course
end

def create
  @spr_type_course = SprTypeCourse.new(spr_type_course_params)

  if @spr_type_course.save
    render json: @spr_type_course, status: :created, location: @spr_type_course
  else
    render json: @spr_type_course.erros, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

def update
  if @spr_type_course.update(spr_type_course_params)
    render json: @spr_type_course
  else
    render json: @spr_type_course.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

def destroy
  @spr_type_course.destroy
end

private
  def set_spr_type_course
    @spr_type_course = SprTypeCourse.find(params[:id])
  end

# Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
def spr_type_course_params

  params.permit(
      :typecourse_id,
      :date_begin,
      :date_end,
      :name,
      :comments,
      :active_id
  )
end
end
```

Comment: Show your db/schema.rb file around where it creates 'PROJECTS'. The error message implies 'BEGIN_DATE' may not be NULL.

Comment: I have no such file, I connect remotely to the database

Comment: You need to know the database structure details in order to program against it.

Comment: @user9997575 can u post form_for, where calling from html form part.

Comment: Add to your post what breed of database you use. If it's MySQL, run `SHOW CREATE TABLE PROJECTS` to see if it permits NULL there. For other databases, run the equivalent that dumps out your schema for that table.

Comment: try changing `params.permit(....)` to `params.require(spr_type_courses_controller).permit(...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `spr_type_course_params` is the problem.
As you can see in the error log, the `spr_type_course` parameter is not being allowed in the strong parameters. Also, `spr_type_course` parameter is empty. Please review the submitted form too.

> {"spr_type_course"=>{}} Unpermitted parameter:

Change it by the following:

```
def spr_type_course_params
  # here I assume the typecourse_id, date_begin etc params are all 
  # included in spr_type_course schema
  params.require(:spr_type_course).permit(
      :typecourse_id,
      :date_begin,
      :date_end,
      :name,
      :comments,
      :active_id
  )
end
```